# How to redirect Boost.Log to file

Tags: c++, logging, boost-log

I want a simple log file in a concurrent application. I've download `Boost.Log` v2.0 and using compiled it with `Boost 1.53.0`.

The problem is that `Boost.Log` output on console. I'm using `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace)`.

Is there a nice way to redirect `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` to a file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can make `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` use a file. Note that most of the `boost::log` examples use a namespace alias as shown below.

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;

void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log("sample.log");

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
```

And in main:

```
int main(int, char*[])
{
    init();

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
 // other types of severity
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what header have I to include for logging::add_file_log("sample.log") ?

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: `#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>`